# Twilio - getSubscribedChannels / getLocalChannels returns wrong sorting on first load

Tags: twilio

for our project, we are using twilio to implement a chat. When we get the user channels, we want to get them sorted by lastMessage, descending. For that, we did as described in this post [Twilio - channel descriptor paginator order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344782/twilio-channel-descriptor-paginator-order/58396137#58396137) with getSubscribedChannels() and getLocalChannels, where we pass "criteria: 'lastMessage', order: 'descending'".

the problem is that on first time we load the page, we don't get the channels in the expected order. The channel with the last message is not on top of the list. When I reload the page, then it's in the correct order.

Does someone know why we get this problem ?

Thanks.
lausav

Comment: I'm sort of in the same situation. When I call getSubscribedChannels the order is not guaranteed to be latest updated channels first. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hi savaryl,  @James -  Did you guys find a solution for this? I have the same issue

Comment: @tsikka, the only solution I could come up with was to load all the channels with a recursive loop and then sort them myself.